# Android: Items/Layout is not being positioned anther item/layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to set a button underneath three textviews/edittexts, but the button is not appearing on the screen for some reason. I have tried setting the orientation of the outside layout to vertical, but that does not work. I have also tried explicitly setting the button underneath the texts, but that did not work either.

I pretty much want the three text to be in the middle and on the same line, and the button in the middle but underneath the three texts.

Here is what I have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/timer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_layout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hour_value"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="45sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="00" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_colon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="45sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text=":" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/minute_value"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="45sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="00" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/timer_layout"
        >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_timer_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="START TIMER"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second LinearLayout change

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Also, flags like

```
android:layout_above="@+id/button_layout"
```

are for RelativeLayout and have no use for LinearLayout.

**EDIT:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/hour_value"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="00"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/minute_value"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/first_colon"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/first_colon"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_colon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text=":"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/minute_value"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="00"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first_colon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/first_colon"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_timer_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="START TIMER"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hour_value"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Also doesn't look like you'd need the `LineaLayout` for the `Button`.

Comment: So I should completely get rid of the layout for the button? Also, it works but how can I get the texts to be at the center center? Its now at the top center of the screen but the button is at the center center (the way it should).